# IICS - populate TIMESTAMP_TZ column with generated value

Tags: informatica, iics, iics-di

I am trying to populate TIMESTAMP_TZ column in Snowflake using the Informatica IICS from the Taskflow. In the taskflow I am using function fn:current-dateTime() which I am trying then in the mapping to convert to TIMESTAMP_TZ using the to_date() function but I am getting error

```
MAPPING> TE_7002 [2023-01-17 11:07:50.987] Transformation stopped due to a fatal error in the mapping.  The expression [To_Date($$inp_load_dttm)] contains the following errors [<<PM Parse Error>> [$$inp_load_dttm)]: Invalid date value string: >>>2023-01-17T16:06:58.019Z<<<.
... To_Date(>>>>$$inp_load_dttm<<<<)].
MANAGER> PETL_24005 [2023-01-17 11:07:50.988] Starting post-session tasks. : (Tue Jan 17 11:07:50 2023)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fn:current-dateTime()` returns `date` ([ref 1](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=functions-fncurrent-datetime-function)). `to_date` expects a string ([ref 2](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/transformation-language-reference/functions/to_date.html)). Here in this case you should not try to conver a `date` to `date` - it should simply work. If what you need is just the date, without the time, try using `fn:current-date()`.